# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'streams' (Pytube with PySimpleGUI)

Tags: python, youtube, pysimplegui

I am an absolutely newbie when it comes to python. So far I had no problem with running my py without GUI. Now I wanted to create a GUI and I got an ERROR.

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'streams'

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
from pytube import YouTube
import os

sg.theme('Reddit')
choices = ("MP3", "MP4")
yt = YouTube

layout = [[sg.Text("Enter URL:"), sg.Input(key='-URL-')],
          [sg.Listbox(choices, size=(8, len(choices)), key='-CHOICES-')],
          [sg.Submit(button_color="green"), sg.Cancel(button_color="red")]]

window = sg.Window("YouTube Downloader", layout)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event in (sg.WIN_CLOSED, 'Cancel'):
        break
    elif event == 'Submit':
        yt = [values['-URL-']]
        filetype = [values['-CHOICES-']]
if "-URL-" == choices[1]:
    yt = yt.streams.get_highest_resolution()
    datatype = '.mp4'
else:
    yt = yt.streams.get_audio_only()
    datatype = '.mp3'

destination = "C:\\Users\\Maintain\\Desktop\\testfolder"
out_file = yt.download(output_path=destination)
base, ext = os.path.splitext(out_file)
new_file = base + datatype
os.rename(out_file, new_file)

sg.popup(yt.title + "has been successfully downloaded.")

window.close()
```

Comment: You assign `yt = YouTube` near the top. Then later in your `elif event == ‘Submit’:` block you assign a list to the `yt` variable … `yt = [values[‘-URL-‘]]` and additionally you reassign it again further down to be the return value from `yt.streams.get_highest_resolution()` which I believe is when your error pops. I imagine you are needing another variable so you can leave `yt` as the class `YouTube`.

Comment: Additionally, you likely should use `from pytube import YouTube as yt` as that is cleaner. You would then remove your initial assignment: `yt = YouTube` you would still need to not reassign anything to the variable `yt`.